# How do I fix the unwrapped version of my knife?

Tags: workflow, uv-image-editor

The first picture below is the tutorial I´m following and the second one is mine.

Why do they look so different? And how do I fix it?

the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPoxqOcUzNQ&list=PL3UWN2F2M2C8-zUjbFlbgtWPQa0NXBsp0&index=6

update:
I unmarked everey seam and did it againg and it worked! I hav no idea what i did wrong but it works now. My guess is that i had marked some seams that you couldn´t see or someting

[[image]]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you haven't marked exactly the same set of seams as the instructor and that when you unwrap  you didn't use exactly the same set of unwrap options.  Go back through the tutorial and make sure you have the seams the same as the instructor.  It looks like you've marked a lot more seams than they did, which is why there are so many more objects (islands) in your UV map

Comment: They don't look so different ; but some of your UVs are overlapping. You can fix that by using the "Pack Island" function (in the "UV" menu). Ifg you want a more precise answer, please provide the link to the tutorial !

Comment: or provide your blend file...

Comment: okey, i added a link to the tutorial but i caan´t figure out how i can provide my blend file. I did the "pack island" and have now updated tha image above

Answer (score 0):

When you unwrap objects, there is a slider for the "Margin" that you could use. Another things is that even if you cut the same areas as in the tutorial, probably some parts will have a different orientation; that could be fixed manually with rotation

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. That madi it alot easier to ovrersee what it is.